# How to save a Python interactive session?

Tags: python, shell, read-eval-print-loop, interactive-session

I find myself frequently using Python's interpreter to work with databases, files, etc -- basically a lot of manual formatting of semi-structured data.  I don't properly save and clean up the useful bits as often as I would like.  Is there a way to save my input into the shell (db connections, variable assignments, little for loops and bits of logic) -- some history of the interactive session?  If I use something like `script` I get too much stdout noise.  I don't really need to pickle all the objects -- though if there is a solution that does that, it would be OK.  Ideally I would just be left with a script that ran as the one I created interactively, and I could just delete the bits I didn't need.  Is there a package that does this, or a DIY approach?

Answer (score 458, accepted):

[IPython](https://ipython.org/) is extremely useful if you like using interactive sessions. For example for your use-case there is [the `%save` magic command](http://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html#magic-save), you just input `%save my_useful_session 10-20 23` to save input lines 10 to 20 and 23 to `my_useful_session.py` (to help with this, every line is prefixed by its number).

Furthermore, the documentation states:

> This function uses the same syntax as [%history](http://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/5.x/interactive/magics.html#magic-history) for input ranges, then saves the lines to the filename you specify.

This allows for example, to reference older sessions, such as

```
%save current_session ~0/
%save previous_session ~1/
```

Look at [the videos on the presentation page](https://ipython.org/presentation.html) to get a quick overview of the features.

Comment: How to save all the lines? Without specifying the range, it creates an empty file. :(

Comment: @balki, IPython's prompt tells you how many lines are in your history (i.e. `In[48]`).  So `save filename 1-48` would save your whole session.

Comment: Also, is it possible to load this file back into ipython and keep your input history intact?

Comment: hmm, I get SyntaxError: invalid syntax when I try it in the Enthought pylab prompt ... it's supposed to be IPython 12.1, and I can't find this save command documented on the IPython site ...

Comment: @SamJoseph: Please use %save my_useful_session 10-20 23 (as in the example post) don't forget the percentage-sign

Comment: feinmann - thanks - that's it - maybe I can edit the answer to make that obvious ... but apparently not as edits have to be at least 6 characters ...

Comment: @BenPage Use "ipython -i [filename]" on the saved .py file, from the bash promt in order to load the file back before returning to an interactive console! (without the -i flag you don't get the interactive console after running the file).

Comment: Where is this function? When I try from ipython, there is a save function but "help(save)" says save is not defined. If I load ipython --pylab, then the "save" function is not the same, it is the one from numpy. I want to call ipython.save from ipython but when I'm using pylab if possible.

Comment: @mathtick: there's a difference between Python functions and IPython commands (latter are like a shell built-in in *nix) - so command to use is %save which is part if IPython.  See http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/rel-0.10.2/html/interactive/tutorial.html#source-code-handling-tips

Comment: If you want to append to the file rather than overwrite it, save using the `-a` option.  Example: `%save -a my_useful_session 10-20 23`

Comment: So how does one restore the %save afterwards?

Comment: @user4779, as one would expect: `%load my_useful_session`

Comment: The simplest way by far is Linux Python2 is Roberto's answer below.  All built-in and just plain works.  `import readline` then `readline.write_history_file('/home/ahj/history')`

Comment: Problem is I'm trying to use virtualenv which doesn't play nice with jupyter

Comment: @balki the whole current session can be specified with `~0/`

Comment: seems that there is not proper way of doing this in python if everyone is trying to ram jupyter down our throats. which I'm still really really iffy about.

Comment: how to save just few lines from interactive session in pycharm

Answer (score 214):

From Andrew Jones's website ([archived](https://web.archive.org/web/20130218140009/http://www.andrewhjon.es:80/save-interactive-python-session-history)):

```
import readline
readline.write_history_file('/home/ahj/history')
```

Comment: Creates an empty file for me on windows 7

Comment: Worked like a charm for me in Ubuntu.

Comment: @ubershmekel - Looks like it [only works on Unix](https://docs.python.org/2.6/library/readline.html)

Comment: Fails on my TI-83

Comment: Remember to do it at the end of your session. Mine was looking a bit empty after calling the function only at the start.

Comment: works on Python 2.7.2 (default, Jun 12 2011, 15:08:59) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win 32; Windows 7

Comment: blank for me on Ubuntu 16.04 Python 3.6

Comment: Gives me a bunch of weird crap on macOS

Comment: PERFECT for Python2 on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and on the Raspberry Pi.  No special sauce required.  All built-in.  Thanks much!

Comment: Works for me on MacOS

Comment: Works on Ubuntu 16.04.3 Python 3.5.2, but it saves all history instead of just the current session

Comment: Link seems to be broken now, just shows `connecting...` white screen

Comment: Very useful when you have just Python at hands.

Comment: This gave me the whole history of Python sessions on my computer, months of programming. Was interesting.

Comment: saved a blank file on Ubuntu 20.04

Answer (score 101):

There is a [way](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/interactive.html?highlight=atexit) to do it. Store the file in `~/.pystartup`...

```
# Add auto-completion and a stored history file of commands to your Python
# interactive interpreter. Requires Python 2.0+, readline. Autocomplete is
# bound to the Esc key by default (you can change it - see readline docs).
#
# Store the file in ~/.pystartup, and set an environment variable to point
# to it:  "export PYTHONSTARTUP=/home/user/.pystartup" in bash.
#
# Note that PYTHONSTARTUP does *not* expand "~", so you have to put in the
# full path to your home directory.

import atexit
import os
import readline
import rlcompleter

historyPath = os.path.expanduser("~/.pyhistory")

def save_history(historyPath=historyPath):
    import readline
    readline.write_history_file(historyPath)

if os.path.exists(historyPath):
    readline.read_history_file(historyPath)

atexit.register(save_history)
del os, atexit, readline, rlcompleter, save_history, historyPath
```

and then set the environment variable `PYTHONSTARTUP` in your shell (e.g. in `~/.bashrc`):

```bash
export PYTHONSTARTUP=$HOME/.pystartup
```

You can also add this to get autocomplete for free:

```
readline.parse_and_bind('tab: complete')
```

Please note that this will only work on *nix systems. As readline is only available in Unix platform.

Comment: Mac OS X uses editline, so there is tab-complete functionality available, but the exact command is different: readline.parse_and_bind("bind ^I rl_complete")

Comment: That was crazy fast, Nadia, many thanks.  I will try both of the answers -- target platform is Ubuntu, BTW

Comment: `readline.parse_and_bind('tab: complete')` works if you use MacPorts Python.

Comment: This should be framed. Worked on RHEL 6.6. Pyenv, 2.7.10.

Comment: Why I didn't search for this all of these years!
This solution is great as uses original tool that is fast and light.

Comment: just a "me too" to say that I use this manually when debugging unstable code since the atexit doesn't happen if the interpreter segfaults. Thanks again for the great suggestion!

Answer (score 79):

If you are using [IPython](http://ipython.org/) you can save to a file all your previous commands using the magic function *[%history](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/2/api/generated/IPython.core.magics.history.html#IPython.core.magics.history.HistoryMagics)* with the *-f* parameter, p.e:

```
%history -f /tmp/history.py
```

Comment: Wasnt sure about the location of the file using `save` magic. This was very helpful

Comment: Use `%history -g -f full_history.py` to get history from all sessions, not just the current one. See also: [documentation for %history](http://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html#magic-history).

Answer (score 23):

After installing [Ipython](http://ipython.org/), and opening an Ipython session by running the command:

```
ipython
```

from your command line, just run the following Ipython 'magic' command to automatically log your entire  Ipython session:

```
%logstart
```

This will create a uniquely named .py file and store your session for later use as an interactive Ipython session or for use in the script(s) of your choosing.

Answer (score 14):

Also, [reinteract](http://blog.fishsoup.net/2007/11/10/reinteract-better-interactive-python/) gives you a notebook-like interface to a Python session.

Comment: `reinteract` is now superseded by the IPython Notebook and QtConsole.

Answer (score 11):

In addition to IPython, a similar utility [bpython](http://bpython-interpreter.org/) has a "save the code you've entered to a file" feature

Comment: can anybody explain how this is done with bpython? I tried ctrl+s but it didn't work (version 0.14.2 on top of Python 3.4.3 running Gnome terminal)

Comment: It's bound to F7 by default.  F1 will show you the help and current keybindings.

Comment: F7 launches the external editor.  Ctrl+s should prompt for a simple save to file feature, but it's bound to "stop" in bash and zsh, so you'll need to choose an alternative in the bpython config.

Answer (score 11):

I had to struggle to find an answer, I was very new to iPython environment.

This will work

If your iPython session looks like this

```
In [1] : import numpy as np
....
In [135]: counter=collections.Counter(mapusercluster[3])
In [136]: counter
Out[136]: Counter({2: 700, 0: 351, 1: 233})
```

You want to save lines from 1 till 135 then on the same ipython session use this command

```
In [137]: %save test.py 1-135
```

This will save all your python statements in test.py file in your current directory ( where you initiated the ipython).

Comment: how to do this in pycharm with anaconda

Answer (score 4):

There is %history magic for printing and saving the input history (and optionally the output).

To store your current session to a file named `my_history.py`:

```
>>> %hist -f my_history.py
```

History IPython stores both the commands you enter, and the results it produces. You can easily go through previous commands with the up- and down-arrow keys, or access your history in more sophisticated ways.

You can use the %history magic function to examine past input and output. Input history from previous sessions is saved in a database, and IPython can be configured to save output history.

Several other magic functions can use your input history, including %edit, %rerun, %recall, %macro, %save and %pastebin. You can use a standard format to refer to lines:

```
%pastebin 3 18-20 ~1/1-5
```

This will take line 3 and lines 18 to 20 from the current session, and lines 1-5 from the previous session.

See %history? for the Docstring and more examples.

Also, be sure to explore the capabilities of [%store magic](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/rel-0.12/config/extensions/storemagic.html) for lightweight persistence of variables in IPython.

> Stores variables, aliases and macros in IPython’s database.

```
d = {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
%store d  # stores the variable
del d

%store -r d  # Refresh the variable from IPython's database.
>>> d
{'a': 1, 'b': 2}
```

To autorestore stored variables on startup, specify`c.StoreMagic.autorestore = True` in ipython_config.py.

Comment: Enabling saving output history can be done by enabling `c.HistoryManager.db_log_output` in the config file.

Answer (score 4):

The `%history` command is awesome, but unfortunately it won't let you save things that were %paste 'd into the sesh.  To do that I think you have to do `%logstart` [at the beginning](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31749395/4549682) (although I haven't confirmed this works).

What I like to do is

`%history -o -n -p -f filename.txt`

which will save the output, line numbers, and '>>>' before each input (o, n, and p options).  See the docs for %history [here](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/2/api/generated/IPython.core.magics.history.html#IPython.core.magics.history.HistoryMagics).

Answer (score 3):

Just putting another suggesting in the bowl:
[Spyder](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder)

[image]

It has *History log* and *Variable explorer*. If you have worked with MatLab, then you'll see the similarities.

Answer (score 2):

As far as Linux goes, one can use `script` command to record the whole session. It is part of `util-linux` package so should be on most Linux systems  .  You can create and alias or function that will call `script -c python` and that will be saved to a `typescript` file.  For instance, here's a reprint of one such file.

```
$ cat typescript                                                                                                      
Script started on Sat 14 May 2016 08:30:08 AM MDT
Python 2.7.6 (default, Jun 22 2015, 17:58:13) 
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> print 'Hello Pythonic World'
Hello Pythonic World
>>> 

Script done on Sat 14 May 2016 08:30:42 AM MDT
```

Small disadvantage here is that the `script` records everything , even line-feeds, whenever you hit backspaces , etc. So you may want to use `col` to clean up the output (see [this post on Unix&Linux Stackexchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/86901/85039)) .

Answer (score 1):

there is another option --- pyslice.
in the "wxpython 2.8 docs demos and tools", there is a  open source program named "pyslices".

you can use it like a editor, and it also support using like a console ---- executing each line like a interactive interpreter with immediate echo.

of course, all the blocks of codes and results of each block will be recorded into a txt file automatically.

the results are logged just behind the corresponding block of code. very convenient.

[image: the overview of pyslices]

Comment: PySlices author here. Glad you like PySlices (and that you even found it). It's not quite abandon-ware yet (I actually still use it), but the version included in wxPython itself often doesn't work well. If you want to follow updates you can get them from the wx_py package: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/wx_py, https://github.com/davidmashburn/wx_py

Answer (score 1):

In [IPython](https://ipython.org/), I first use

```
In [2]: %hist
```

to view my past code. I select the chunk I want to save and then paste it into file `my_file.py` using the `%%file` magic (short for [`%%writefile`](https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/dev/interactive/magics.html#cellmagic-writefile))

```
In [3]: %%file my_file.py
   ...: # paste code here 
   ...:  
   ...:
```

hitting return two times in the end.

To append to file use the option `-a`: `%%file -a my_file.py`.

If needed, I can list, edit, etc. the file in the underlying command line using the exclamation mark

```
In [5]: !ls -l my_file.py
In [6]: !vi my_file.py
```

Answer (score 0):

Some comments were asking how to save all of the IPython inputs at once. For %save magic in IPython, you can save all of the commands programmatically as shown below, to avoid the prompt message and also to avoid specifying the input numbers. 
    currentLine = len(In)-1
    %save -f my_session 1-$currentLine

The `-f` option is used for forcing file replacement and the `len(IN)-1` shows the current input prompt in IPython, allowing you to save the whole session programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

For those using `spacemacs`, and `ipython` that comes with `python-layer`, save magic creates a lot of unwanted output, because of the constant auto-completion command working in the backround such as:

```
len(all_suffixes)
';'.join(__PYTHON_EL_get_completions('''len'''))
';'.join(__PYTHON_EL_get_completions('''all_substa'''))
len(all_substantives_w_suffixes)
';'.join(__PYTHON_EL_get_completions('''len'''))
';'.join(__PYTHON_EL_get_completions('''all'''))
';'.join(__PYTHON_EL_get_completions('''all_'''))
';'.join(__PYTHON_EL_get_completions('''all_w'''))
';'.join(__PYTHON_EL_get_completions('''all_wo'''))
';'.join(__PYTHON_EL_get_completions('''all_wor'''))
';'.join(__PYTHON_EL_get_completions('''all_word'''))
';'.join(__PYTHON_EL_get_completions('''all_words'''))
len(all_words_w_logograms)
len(all_verbs)
```

To avoid this just save the ipython buffer like you normally save any other: `spc f s`

Answer (score 0):

If you use **bpython**, all your command history is by default saved to `~/.pythonhist`.

To save the commands for later reusage you can copy them to a python script file:

```
$ cp ~/.pythonhist mycommands.py
```

Then edit that file to clean it up and [put it under Python path](http://djangotricks.blogspot.com/2008/09/note-on-python-paths.html) (global or virtual environment's site-packages, current directory, mentioning in *.pth, or some other way).

To include the commands into your shell, just import them from the saved file:

```
>>> from mycommands import *
```

Comment: life savior. a hard to find answer

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to suggest another way to maintain python session through tmux on linux. you run tmux, attach your self to the session you opened (if not attached after opening it directly). execute python and do whatever you are doing on it. then detach from session. detaching from a tmux session does not close the session. the session remains open.

**pros of this method:**
you can attach to this session from any other device (in case you can ssh your pc)

**cons of this method:**
this method does not relinquish the resources used by the opened python session until you actually exist the python interpreter.

Answer (score 0):

**To save input and output on XUbuntu**:

1. In XWindows, run iPython from the Xfce terminal app
2. click `Terminal` in the top menu bar and look for `save contents` in the dropdown

I find this saves the input and output, going all the way back to when I opened the terminal.  This is not ipython specific, and would work with ssh sessions or other tasks run from the terminal window.

Answer (score -1):

You can use built-in function open: I use it in all of my
programs in which I need to store some history (Including Calculator, etc.)
for example:

```
#gk-test.py or anything else would do
try: # use the try loop only if you haven't created the history file outside program
    username = open("history.txt").readline().strip("\n")
    user_age = open("history.txt").readlines()[1].strip("\n")
except FileNotFoundError:
    username = input("Enter Username: ")
    user_age = input("Enter User's Age: ")
    open("history.txt", "w").write(f"{username}\n{user_age}")
#Rest of the code is secret! try it your own!
```

I would thank to all of them who liked my comments! Thank you for reading this!