# Interactive python

Tags: python

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to save a Python interactive session?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/947810/how-to-save-a-python-interactive-session)

Can i save everything I type into a python session when "brain storming"?

For instance, not just default variables but of course even overriding the shell. I of course mean by invoking the actual python executable.

I seriously hope this is not a stupid question.

I need rep of course too, so this probes me a bit.

Comment: Exact duplicate, I believe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/947810/how-to-save-a-python-interactive-session

Comment: Indeed, had my search been just a little different.

Answer (score 9):

iPython (as suggested in another answer) is indeed a good suggestion, but if you prefer the good old Python interactive interpreter it's not too hard to do it there either. Set your environment variable `PYTHONSTARTUP` to point to a file that contains, for example:

```
import atexit
import readline
try:
    readline.read_history_file('.PythonHistory')
except OSError:
    pass
atexit.register(lambda: readline.write_history_file('.PythonHistory'))
```

this can be tweaked as you wish (e.g. to load and save the same file no matter what directory you're starting from) but I kind of like this simple version as it makes it very easy to have different "sessions" remembered in different working directories.

Comment: I like this the best. I wanted this type of control and thank you for the imports.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if you can do this with the Python shell.  But it's possible with IPython which gives you a lot more:

- http://ipython.scipy.org/moin/Cookbook/SavingCurrentSession

Answer (score 2):

Others (ars, Alex Martelli) have given direct answers to the question.  For myself, I've found a more effective strategy is to write all of the commands into a text editors and either execute saved scripts and/or copy-and-paste into python or ipython.  I find that I can keep myself more organized that way.

Answer (score 0):

There is as well the Bpython interpreter :

http://www.bpython-interpreter.org/

This is the list of features which include the save code and even send the code
to a pastebin service.

- In-line syntax highlighting.
- Readline-like autocomplete with suggestions displayed as you type.
- Expected parameter list for any Python function.
- "Rewind" function to pop the last line of code from memory and re-evaluate.
- Send the code you've entered off to a pastebin.
- Save the code you've entered to a file.
- Auto-indentation.