# Where are functions saved in Python and will they still remain after I close the cmd

Tags: python

I'm new with Python and I created a method that clears the screen. Is it already saved somewhere in my computer so that everytime I call it in Python cmd I can use it?

Something to add:
Should I learn Python 2 or 3 is fine enough?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it will be gone when you start a new session.  If you want to add your shortcut so that it's there every time you start python, you have a few options:

- Add it in your `sitecustomize.py` file, this may be platform dependent but for my system it is located at `/usr/lib/python2.7/sitecustomize.py`.
- Add it in your `ipy_user_conf.py` for ipython.  On unix systems it should be under `~/.ipython/`.  I have actually already the same alias to clear the screen 3x on mine, by adding the line `o.autoexec.append('alias c clear; clear; clear')` under `main()` in `ipy_user_conf.py`
- Define it in your own module, and autoimport this module at python startup (using sitecustomize, PYTHONPATH environment variable, or whatever..)

The adoption curve of python 3 is poor because many people are relying on packages that are still only supported properly by python 2.x.   You should learn python 2 if you are going to use libraries that don't have good python 3 support yet, otherwise learn python 3 because it does have many significant improvements.  The authors have a tool to convert 2 to 3 which can handle most syntax stuff automatically, for simple enough code.

Answer (score 2):

No. Each interactive session is separate. However, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/947810/how-to-save-a-python-interactive-session) for ways to save sessions if you want to.