# Can Python 2.x save the globals from the interpreter to a file?

Tags: code-generation, interpreter, python

Writing things like the bound variables with current values and names, already entered code of defined functions, imports at the beginning, etc., to a .py file? (on **win32**, just for the lack of built in readline).

**EDIT** Just the standard installation/package, without things like iPython. :)

I can make python save a **history file** on clean exits, but I'm interested if there is any way to make the interpreter dump some code it already has. In a human readable format.

It's not a problem at all if it's not exactly the same I entered while the functionality and the visible names are the same.

**Reason** just curious.

---

Useless reasons: it would come handy when you hastily help out a friend at an unknown terminal while [s]he's learning the language, just to realize that there is no convenient way to save the work, while putting it into a file and running that arguably would have made things harder to gasp for the comrade. I'm aware there are things like [playerpiano](https://code.google.com/p/playerpiano/), but you see, it's a random terminal where you have no admin rights and there is not internet. :) Happened several times at school, by the way. Please note that the main reason is being curious.

Comment: Looks like iPython is what you're looking for :)
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/947810/how-to-save-a-python-interactive-session

Comment: I love ipython but I'm curious if a more bare solution exists. the other question is superb by the way, if I can install something.

Comment: If you're trying to come up with your own solution, I would check out the [inspect module](http://docs.python.org/library/inspect.html)

Comment: Also the [dis](http://docs.python.org/library/dis.html) module may help as well.

Answer (score 2):

Some Python shells give you a chance to save your work.  IDLE will let you save the text of the interactive session to a file, for example, so at least you have the text of the things you've created.

IPython offers [IPython Notebook](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/stable/interactive/htmlnotebook.html), which lets you save interactive sessions.

Comment: how does IDLE do it? does it get the code from the interpreter, or from it's own extra buffer?

Comment: IDLE is a GUI program, it has its own record of the interaction with the interpreter.