# Give the Python Terminal a Persistent History

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7

Is there a way to tell the interactive Python shell to preserve its history of executed commands between sessions?

While a session is running, after commands have been executed, I can arrow up and access said commands, I'm just wondering if there is some way for a certain number of these commands to be saved until the next time I use the Python shell.

This would be very useful since I find myself reusing commands in a session, that I used at the end of the last session.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to save a Python interactive session?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/947810/how-to-save-a-python-interactive-session)

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Sure you can, with a small startup script. From [Interactive Input Editing and History Substitution](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/interactive.html) in the python tutorial:

```
# Add auto-completion and a stored history file of commands to your Python
# interactive interpreter. Requires Python 2.0+, readline. Autocomplete is
# bound to the Esc key by default (you can change it - see readline docs).
#
# Store the file in ~/.pystartup, and set an environment variable to point
# to it:  "export PYTHONSTARTUP=~/.pystartup" in bash.

import atexit
import os
import readline
import rlcompleter

historyPath = os.path.expanduser("~/.pyhistory")

def save_history(historyPath=historyPath):
    import readline
    readline.write_history_file(historyPath)

if os.path.exists(historyPath):
    readline.read_history_file(historyPath)

atexit.register(save_history)
del os, atexit, readline, rlcompleter, save_history, historyPath
```

From Python 3.4 onwards, [the interactive interpreter supports autocompletion and history out of the box](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.4.html#other-improvements):

> Tab-completion is now enabled by default in the interactive interpreter on systems that support `readline`. History is also enabled by default, and is written to (and read from) the file `~/.python-history`.

Comment: I have several python virtual environments and wanted to be able to enable persistent history. So used this approach, but changed the location of the `.pyhistory` file to the virtual environment folder instead of user home folder.

Answer (score 17):

Use [IPython](http://ipython.org/).

You should, anyway, because it's awesome: persistent command history is just one of the many many ways it's better than the stock Python shell.

Comment: Extra awesome: I just noticed it has Python 3 support now!

Answer (score 1):

This is also required for Python 3 when using a [virtual environment](https://github.com/pypa/virtualenv/issues/355).

I use a slightly different version which keeps a history file per virtual environment:

```
import sys

if sys.version_info >= (3, 0) and hasattr(sys, 'real_prefix'):  # in a VirtualEnv
    import atexit, os, readline, sys

    PYTHON_HISTORY_FILE = os.path.join(os.environ['VIRTUAL_ENV'], '.python_history')
    if os.path.exists(PYTHON_HISTORY_FILE):
        readline.read_history_file(PYTHON_HISTORY_FILE)
    atexit.register(readline.write_history_file, PYTHON_HISTORY_FILE)
```