# Block command history access in shell

Tags: python, bash, python-2.7, shell, readline

I don't want to access the shell command history in shell. It has to block for temporary purpose and after that I am able to release that block.

**e.g.** when I press `up arrow` in shell it shows the last command present in history, But i don't want to access history when I press up arrow on shell

Can we block history from accessing it?

i have tried `set +o history`  but its for different purpose.

```
shell:> ifconfig
shell:> #some shell.py
Login: #when I press up arrow, "ifconfig" comes here as that was last command
Password:
```

for **Login:** it only has to access input, don't access history here.
After accepting Login and Password then i can able to access history again.

Comment: Don't use [`readline`](https://cnswww.cns.cwru.edu/php/chet/readline/rltop.html) in `shell.py` (or start with a clean readline history)

Comment: i can't use `clean history` , it will delete all history of current session. I have to use history again after blocking it temporary @hek2mgl

Comment: Is this really a question about [bash] and [shell], or it is a question about [python] and [readline]?

Comment: [bash] and [shell] @gboffi ,  any doubt ??

Comment: Yes, I doubt it. You should fix that problem on Python side

Comment: How??? @hek2mgl

Comment: it is a question about [python] and [readline]?   you were right @gboffi

Comment: I don't exactly how atm. If I'll find time today I'll have a look at this

Comment: ok no problem @hek2mgl

Comment: Who wrote `shell.py`? You or a third party? Do you have access to its source code? — Imho the problem is in `shell.py` that misuse the readline library to read the user name and their password.  The user name should be read using, simply, `input` and the password should be read using the [`getpass`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/getpass.html#module-getpass) module from the Python standard library

Comment: yes for username we have read by using `raw_input` and password by using `getpass` @gboffi ,   still its not working

Comment: Can you show the most basic example of Python code which you are using? That's necessary to reproduce the problem

Answer (score 0):

You can disable the Up Arrow Key by editing your `~/.bashrc` and adding :

`bind '"\e[A": '`

Meaning : Bind `Up Arrow Key` to nothing

(You will need to reload it or re-open your session)

To re-enable it, simply remove the line and reload the `.bashrc` file

Answer (score 0):

To remove up-arrow binding

```
bind -r '\e[A'
```

To restore

```
bind '"\e[A": previous-history'
```

To retrieve all bindings to `previous-history`

```
bind -p | grep previous-history
```

or

```
bind -q previous-history
```

see also

```
help bind
```

Comment: its only blocks `up arrow`, but when we hit `ctrl+p`  this will access history again @NahuelFouilleul

Comment: do you want to block all bindings to previous-history or prevent last command to be added in history list?

Comment: all bindings to previous history @NahuelFouilleul

Comment: I am getting error as `/bin/sh: 1: bind: not found`   @NahuelFouilleul  when running it with `subprocess.call()`

Comment: can i use same in `python shell`  @NahuelFouilleul

Comment: bind is a `bash` builtin, it affects only current shell session, launching a process from python could not affect python session

Comment: it seems it's not possible directly with python, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/12782553/1454708, and 2 answers below