# Python Interpreter Code Completion

Tags: macos, unix, code-completion, python

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I add tab completion to the Python shell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/246725/how-do-i-add-tab-completion-to-the-python-shell)

Is there an easy way to add code completion feature to a Python interpreter that is started on a unix console?

Comment: Related: [Give the Python Terminal a Persistent History](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12334316)

Answer (score 0):

You should really install something like `ipython` or `bpython`

```
pip install ipython
```

This will give you a much better python interpreter that offers code completion, history and other magical functions that will make your python experience much better!

Answer (score 0):

Try using [ipython](http://ipython.org/) which amoungst other things adds a shell which includes code completion to the intepreter.

Answer (score 0):

Yes! Take a look at [bpython](http://bpython-interpreter.org/)!

You should be able to install it with pip. I actually have it in my Linux distro as a package.

Answer (score -4):

Nope thats not possible, you need to use an IDE.

Comment: This is wrong answer