# Save command history between sessions in IDLE

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-idle

Is there a way to save input entered into IDLE Shell window persistently? Is there standard setting or [manual way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12334344/911419) is the only way? Previous history/Next history (Alt-P/Alt-N) do not work between sessions.

Does [IPython](https://ipython.org/install.html) works for IDLE as well?

Answer (score 0):

IDLE Shell is a specialized editor window and you same it the same way as when editing.

IPython is somewhat similar but different IDE.  It is somewhat aimed at people with more experience and it has different design constraints.

Comment: So IPython is not a case here. What is the possible solution for IDLE?

Comment: I already answered (but corrected the typo).  File => Save as and, once saved, File => Save