# How can I save the code written in an IPython session?

Tags: python, ipython

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to save a Python interactive session?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/947810/how-to-save-a-python-interactive-session)

Is it possible, and if so, how do I save the code that I have written in an IPython session?

Optimally I would only output the code that runs without errors, but exporting all the code would go a long way as well, I suppose.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

`%save my_useful_session 10-20 23`

to save input lines 10 to 20 and 23 to `my_useful_session.py`

Comment: Try `save?` to see how to use it. You can also use `lsmagic` to see the available magic commands.