# How can I log IPython's output without the ugly 7 lines of logging-info on every load?

Tags: python, logging, installation, ipython, dotfiles

My objective is to call `ipython`, while also logging all input/output to IPython, and see something like:

```
stu@stumac ~  $ ipython

In [1]: exit
stu@stumac ~  $
```

The banner can be easily removed if I set

`c.TerminalIPythonApp.display_banner = False`

in my 
`~/.ipython/profile-default/ipython_config.py` file.

**But how do I get this clean of a startup while also logging things?**

On a fresh install, if I start IPython with no parameters I see:

```
sente@og ~ $ ipython
Python 2.7.3 (default, Jun 20 2013, 12:50:58)
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

IPython 0.13.2 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.
?         -> Introduction and overview of IPython's features.
%quickref -> Quick reference.
help      -> Python's own help system.
object?   -> Details about 'object', use 'object??' for extra details.

In [1]: exit
sente@og ~ $
```

If I pass a `logfile=logfile.txt` argument when invoking IPython I see:

```
sente@og ~ $ ipython --logfile=logfile.txt
Activating auto-logging. Current session state plus future input saved.
Filename       : logfile.txt
Mode           : backup
Output logging : False
Raw input log  : False
Timestamping   : False
State          : active
Python 2.7.3 (default, Jun 20 2013, 12:50:58)
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

IPython 0.13.2 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.
?         -> Introduction and overview of IPython's features.
%quickref -> Quick reference.
help      -> Python's own help system.
object?   -> Details about 'object', use 'object??' for extra details.

In [1]: exit
sente@og ~ $
```

How can I use logging without adding the extra clutter to my terminal:

```
Activating auto-logging. Current session state plus future input saved.
Filename       : logfile.txt
Mode           : backup
Output logging : False
Raw input log  : False
Timestamping   : False
State          : active
```

On other machines I have IPython configured to automatically log things by having a `.ipython/profile_default/startup/01-log-everything.py` which contains the lines:

```
from time import strftime
import os.path

ip = get_ipython()

ldir = ip.profile_dir.log_dir
fname = strftime('%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S') + ".py"
filename = os.path.join(ldir, fname)

ip.run_line_magic('logstart', '-o %s append' % filename)
```

which results in the same clutter as when I add `--logfile=logfile.txt`

Any help on how to properly do this would be appreciated.  I could if nothing else redirect sys.stdout, configure logging and then reset sys.stdout but I'm hoping there's a less hackish solution.

Comment: A similar question was asked here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/947810

Comment: @BugoK , thanks - the question in that post is a bit similar I guess, but what I'm trying to do is very specific and not addressed in that post or anywhere else, as best I can tell.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After looking at the IPython source, namely:

- https://github.com/ipython/ipython/blob/f645e5c044efeacf1aa523ec43f6a25d439e287b/IPython/core/logger.py#L155
- https://github.com/ipython/ipython/blob/f645e5c044efeacf1aa523ec43f6a25d439e287b/IPython/core/magics/logging.py#L135

It seems the only way to actually achieve what I want -- *complete logging **without** anything echo'd upon startup* -- is to redirect or mute `sys.stdout` while initializing the logging.

I've created a startup file: [~/.ipython/profile_default/startup/01-log-everything.py](https://gist.github.com/sente/6068935) which does this, the code is:

```
from time import strftime
import os.path
import contextlib
import cStringIO
import sys


# create a context which we can use for any block which we can use for any
# block which we do not want to print stdout
# -- taken from http://stackoverflow.com/a/2829036/217652

@contextlib.contextmanager
def nostdout():
    save_stdout = sys.stdout
    sys.stdout = cStringIO.StringIO()
    yield
    sys.stdout = save_stdout



ip = get_ipython()

ldir = ip.profile_dir.log_dir
fname = strftime('%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S') + ".py"
filename = os.path.join(ldir, fname)


# stdout is now muted
with nostdout():
    ip.run_line_magic('logstart', '-o %s append' % filename)
```

Answer (score 4):

To log with no banner use the --no-banner flag.

```
ipython --no-banner --logfile='logfile.txt'
```

This can be found in the help file displayed with the --help-all flag.

```
ipython --help-all
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, but I want to prevent the banner *as well as* the all the logging info.  When you pass `--logfile='logfile.txt'`, IPython prints half a dozen lines of stuff which I want to suppress.