# How to save the python scripts made on Python console in Pycharm?

Tags: python, pycharm

I have been writing scripts in Python console provided in Pycharm but now I need to save them on my desktop and run them at some later point. I can not happen to find any option to do so for the console scripts.

Comment: Just save and run with `python <file>.py`...

Comment: I don't follow you. What exactly are you asking how to do?

Comment: I can easily save files and programs in the python project but when I do not find the option to lines that I write in the console in the format of a python program

Comment: This answer might be related to your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/947810/how-to-save-a-python-interactive-session

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a way to save the contents of a console session within PyCharm (or any other editor that I know of). As @daladier pointed out in the comments, though, [iPython](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/stable/overview.html) may be what you are looking for. Using [Jupyter Notebooks](http://jupyter.org/) which are based on iPython you can create interactive cells in notebooks that behave similar to the console.