# Transferring console code to editor in PyCharm

Tags: console, pycharm

My current workflow involves trying out various code snippets in the PyCharm console - I'd rather not have to run everything again every time I encounter an error because this can be time consuming for code that has a long runtime - before copying my process over to the editor.

The problem with this is that there are often hundreds of console entries mixed with errors and it can be a pain to sift through. Is there a way to write a macro or something like that which extracts the non-error-throwing code to the editor (basically the opposite of the 'execute in console' editor tool but with error checking/filtering)? I looked at PyCharm macros but I'm not convinced they're what I'm looking for.

Comment: I haven't tried anything from that, but as PyCharm is uses normal interactive python session, this could be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/947810/how-to-save-a-python-interactive-session