# How to read history in ptpython console?

Tags: python, python-3.x, console, ptpython

I've been trying to figure out how to get save and read in the history of my Python commands in a `ptpython` console, but haven't been able to do so. All of my efforts have so far been variations of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/947820/3991782). However, I still am not able to read in my history.

I would simply like to be able to press the <kbd>↑</kbd> and <kbd>↓</kbd> arrows to go through my Python commands from a previous console session (*not* the current console session that I'm in). Here's what I currently have in my `$PYTHONSTARTUP` file:

```
# Add auto-completion and a stored history file of commands to your Python
# interactive interpreter. Requires Python 2.0+, readline. Autocomplete is
# bound to the Esc key by default (you can change it - see readline docs).
#
# Store the file in ~/.pystartup, and set an environment variable to point
# to it:  "export PYTHONSTARTUP=/home/user/.pystartup" in bash.
#
# Note that PYTHONSTARTUP does *not* expand "~", so you have to put in the
# full path to your home directory.

import atexit
import os
import readline
import rlcompleter
import sys
try:
    from ptpython.repl import embed
except ImportError:
    print('ptpython is not available: falling back to standard prompt')
else:
    sys.exit(embed(globals(), locals()))

historyPath = os.path.expanduser("~/.ptpython/history")

def save_history(historyPath=historyPath):
   import readline
   readline.write_history_file(historyPath)

if os.path.exists(historyPath):
   readline.read_history_file(historyPath)

atexit.register(save_history)
readline.parse_and_bind('tab: complete')
del os, atexit, readline, rlcompleter, save_history, historyPath
```

And my `$PYTHONSTARTUP` variable is:

```
$ echo $PYTHONSTARTUP 
/Users/[redacted]/.pystartup
```

I'm on Python 3.7.3, macOS 10.14.6, and ptpython 2.0.4.

Thanks

Comment: as for me you runs `sys.exit(embed())` so it can't runs code after this line so it can't read history. You would have to read it before `sys.exit(embed())`. If you put `print()` after `sys.exit(embed())` then you will see it is never printed.

Comment: Might help somebody: the potential directories that hold the history if `ptpython` is installed in the user's binaries: `.local/share/ptpython`, `~/.ptpython`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you check source code for [embed](https://github.com/prompt-toolkit/ptpython/blob/master/ptpython/repl.py#L283) then you see option `history_filename=`

```
embed(globals(), locals(), history_filename=historyPath)
```

---

```
import os

try:
    from ptpython.repl import embed
except ImportError:
    print('ptpython is not available: falling back to standard prompt')
else:
    history_path = os.path.expanduser("~/.ptpython/history")
    embed(globals(), locals(), history_filename=history_path)
```

---

**BTW:** If folder `~/.ptpython` doesn't exists then you will have to create it before run code.

**EDIT (2022):**

```
import os

try:
    from ptpython.repl import embed
except ImportError:
    print('ptpython is not available: falling back to standard prompt')
else:
    history_dir  = os.path.expanduser("~/.ptpython")
    history_path = os.path.join(history_dir, "history")
    
    if not os.path.exists(history_path):
        os.makedirs(history_dir, exist_ok=True)  # create folder if not exist
        open(history_path, 'a').close()          # create empty file
        
    embed(globals(), locals(), history_filename=history_path)
```

Comment: I think that this worked! Let me use it for a bit to make sure that everything is functioning correctly, and then I can mark it as correct.